# How to call clearInterval() from HTML to stop setInterval() which is inside the Google Chart JS graph by keeping current graph with data?

Tags: javascript, html, flask, google-visualization, clearinterval

The reason is that Google Chart JS takes data with Ajax from flask provided API. A function setInterval() helps me to have a live graph which is being updated by flask data. The aim is to have additionally a button which would stop this live process but keeps the current graph with current data (no page refresh). So far I have done the live graph successfully, but struggling to stop live graph WITH current data.

What comes to my mind is to call myStopFunction() inside the drawChart function by pressing a button as given in html, but it keeps refreshing.

graph.json

```js
function drawChart() {
    ...
    var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById("chart_div"));
    chart.draw(data, options);


    function importData(){$.ajax({
        url: '/update',
        type: 'POST',
        success: function(data) {
            result = data.value;},
        error: function(error) {
            console.log(error);}
        });
        return result}
   
        var index = 0;
        function addData(){
            results = importData()
            //console.log(result)
            data.addRow([index, result, result+0.5]);
            chart.draw(data, options);
            index++;
        }
        var myVar = setInterval(addData, 1000); 

        function myStopFunction() {
            clearInterval(myVar);
          }      
    }
```

views.py

```py
@app.route('/update', methods=['POST'])
def update():
    data = random()
    return  jsonify({
        'value': data})
```

index.html

```html
...
    <!-- live graph -->
    <div id="chart_div"></div>
    <button onclick="drawChart.myStopFunction();">Stop</button>​
 ...
```

Please let me know if you need more information to clarify the problem or should this either been done in other way.

Answer (score 0):

You should give your interval variable a global scope so it can be accessed from other functions. See following code snippet:

```js
let interval = null // declaring variable interval outside

function drawChart() {
  function addData(){
      console.log("adding data")
  }

  interval = setInterval(addData, 1000); //assigning value to interval variable
}

function myStopFunction() {
  if(interval) {
    console.log("stopping interval")
    clearInterval(interval); //clearing interval if existent
  }
 
}
    
drawChart()
```

```html
<button onclick="myStopFunction();">Stop</button>
```

Do you get an error in the console?
Also, could it be that the ending `}` of the drawChart function should be changed so that the other functions are not inside your drawChart function?

Comment: I do not get any kind of errors in console. I agree that other functions should outside of the drawChart function. But then I cannot find a way to have a live graph to constantly update google chart JS graph with API data.

Comment: Although I haven't worked with Google Chart JS library before, I'm pretty sure there is an update function so your chart does not have to be created every time you update your data but be updated instead.

Comment: I wrote a quick example where clearing the interval is woking fine (have a look at my edited answer). Just check if you can modify your code and if it works then.
The problem you're probably facing at the moment that the scope of your interval variable is not global so your stop function cannot access it.